# Exporting Locations for a Customer using Acumatica API

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to use the Acumatica Web Services API to export all Locations for a Customer.  I would expect that using the Locations screen I could set a filter on the Customer ID field, which I think is LocationSummary.Customer, and that would return me all Locations for that customer.  Instead, I'm always getting 0 results returned.  Code is below, and I've also shown a screen shot of the Locations that exist for a test customer with ID 012349, and the debugger results showing 0 records returned.

```
Public Function GetAddressList(ByVal customerID As String) As String()()
    Dim address As CR303010Content = m_context.CR303010GetSchema()
    m_context.CR303010Clear()

    Dim customerFilter As Filter = New Filter()
    customerFilter.Field = address.LocationSummary.Customer
    customerFilter.Condition = FilterCondition.Equals
    customerFilter.Value = customerID

    Dim searchfilters() As Filter = {customerFilter}
    Dim searchCommands() As Command = {address.LocationSummary.Customer, address.LocationSummary.LocationID, address.GeneralInfoLocationAddress.AddressLine1, address.GeneralInfoLocationAddress.City}
    Dim searchResult As String()() = m_context.CR303010Export(searchCommands, searchfilters, 0, False, False)

    Return searchResult
End Function
```

[image: Locations shown in ERP]

Debugger showing searchResult array with a length of 0
[image: Locations returned in debugger]

Comment: I'd provide another approach. You can create your own Generic Inquiry and collect all required data there and then using Web Services with your own screen export/filter data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your example and couldn't get it to work using filters. I modified it slightly to pass the `customerID` in the search commands instead, and to add `ServiceCommands.EveryLocationID` to it to specify that we want system to loop through all locations:

```
    Dim searchCustomer As New Value() With {.Value = customerID, .LinkedCommand = address.LocationSummary.BusinessAccount}
    Dim searchCommands() As Command = {searchCustomer,
                                       address.LocationSummary.ServiceCommands.EveryLocationID, address.LocationSummary.LocationID, address.GeneralInfoLocationAddress.AddressLine1, address.GeneralInfoLocationAddress.City}
    Dim searchResult As String()() = screen.Export(searchCommands, Nothing, 0, False, False)
```

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel.  That solved my problem and I've marked it as answer.  I'm afraid I still don't understand the solution.  Is that always true that instead of a filter, you can add a value with a .LinkedCommand as the first command and it will achieve the same purpose? Can this be done for multiple filter fields? I also don't understand the 2nd command. Why would the system NOT loop through all locations?  Sorry, I am very new to Acumatica and if there is documentation that explains this, then I would love to have a link to it.  I haven't seen it in our Acumatica system.

Comment: @EricBarr, LocationSummary.BusinessAccount is a key field in this page. When you put something in this field, behaviour of Acumatica is to search for a corresponding record with this value. Same thing happens when you put a value through web services. This screen is a little special, in that it has two key fields (Business Account Code + Location Code).

Comment: @EricBarr if you don't put EveryLocationID, you'll only get the first location ID.